# Can I load just a portion of a page without java script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using PHP for my server side language and have a form that returns results.  I'm currently using jquery to retrieve the results and update a portion of the page.  Can this be done without jquery?  If so are there any good examples?

My current jquery code looks like this:

```
$.post("search_basic_results.php", $("#profile_form_id").serialize(),
    function(data) {    
        $('#search_results').html(data);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to find a java script free alternative but I'm afraid I'll need to reload the entire page again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this be done without jquery?

Yes. jQuery is just a library. It provides helper functions to do things with less code and to iron over differences between browsers.

There are other libraries to choose from (I'm fond of [YUI3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)), and the source code for jQuery is available so you can see what it is doing behind the scenes if you want to.

> I'm trying to find a JavaScript free alternative

You can't edit a document in the browser without client side programming. JavaScript is the only widely supported language for manipulating the browser DOM.

You could use an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) though.

Comment: Would that be the recommended method if I don't want to keep reloading my header and search form?

Comment: If it is just a header and search form, then the recommended method would be to reload them. They will consist of a relatively small amount of HTML (everything else can be cached) and the costs (including breaking bookmarking, link sharing, etc) seriously outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Unfortunately my header loads an image of the logged in user each time it's called.  I'm assuming this will not be cached and require a call to the DB each and every time. Looks similar to the header you see on Twitter.  Looks like they might use an iframe to hold the header...

Comment: It *should* be cached, if it isn't then you need to look at the cache control headers. Likewise, you should store the information about its URL in the user's session when they log in instead of hitting the database every time.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your comment about storing the URL in the users session? I'm not sure I understand that.

Comment: Most systems that allow users to log in will create a session (usually stored in memory or on disk) to mark that the user *is* logged in. Data can be stored in this. If you need data about the user (such as the URL of their profile image) on a regular basis throughout the lifetime of the session, you can store the data there instead of requesting it from the database every time a new page is requested.

Answer (score 2):

Without *Javascript* its not possible.

Here is the old school Javascript code.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","search_basic_results.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be done without jquery?

Sure, you could use plain old javascript AJAX. You will have to write bit of a code. But why would you do this, when you have a cross browser working alternative with jQuery?

As far as manipulating the DOM without javascript is concerned, this cannot be done without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem in reloading the page?

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
{
  // var initialisation
  $input_one = ''; 
  $input_two = '';
  // result wont be displaied
  $display_search = false;
}
else
{
  // this bit keeps track of the input fields
  $input_one = $_POST['input_one'];
  $input_two = $_POST['input_two'];
  // result will be displayed
  $display_search = true;
  // do some stuff that search_basic_results.php would do
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input name="input_one" type="text" value="<?=$input_one?>"/>
  <input name="input_two" type="text" value="<?=$input_two?>"/>
</form>
<? if ($display search == true): ?>
<!-- display stuff you want to display here /  $('#search_results').html(data); equivalent -->
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: Not really a problem , I just like the fact that my header and search form don't flash every time the page needs to be updated. Seems a bit smoother but unfortunately doesn't work if java script is disabled.

Comment: You can check if the browser can use JS, if it does redirect to a page that uses JS. But personally I would prefer seeing my browser flash for a fraction of a second :)